# How can I avoid a full recompile when compiling a C# project with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, compilation, roslyn

I am using Roslyn for some code generation in one of my C# projects. Currently Roslyn will take the entire project, compile it from scratch, then spit out the code I want. This takes a full recompile to do, which is a little slow. When Visual Studio compiles a project it doesn't do it from scratch every time, it does something smart and only re-compiles the parts that have changed. Is there some way to do this with Roslyn?

Comment: "Incremental build" is the term you are looking for.

Comment: C# has never supported incremental builds.

Comment: You missed some key information. Visual Studio is not smart itself, but relies on MSBuild engine to see which projects are already up-to-date. That part is not in Roslyn either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio (in the upcoming version) *uses* Roslyn to compile the code (to IL). For a single project that is not incremental and never was.

Comment: I was aware Roslyn was used by the upcoming VS. I was _not_ aware that VS doesn't do incremental compilation. Now I'm curious why "clean" re-builds take longer than regular builds in my experience. Probably because I'm working with lots of image assets that have to be recopied over to the output directory.

Comment: When MSBuild does a rebuild, we'll attempt to avoid rebuilding _projects_ if we see the result of the build is up to date, via the usual timestamp checks a la Makefiles. But once a file has been modified, we rebuild the entire project, and all it's downstream dependents.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong as I'm not sure about Roslyn, but you may be able to seperate the Roslyn code into another solution and have a seperate solution for your own code.

After that you can simply build the solution that changes all the time.